# Screensaver BlackScreen CommandLine parameters for Login screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, screensaver

I have this screensaver in Windows 7 x64:

C:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr

This is the screensaver which just makes the screen(s) black.

I start it with this command line:

**C:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr**

Does this screensaver support command line parameters?

Usually, I start it without parameters on the command line which just makes the screens black and returns to the normal screen when I move the mouse.

But now I need a command line parameter for **THIS** screensaver to show the login screen when I move the mouse. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Does this screensaver support command line parameters?**

No. Screensavers do not take command line parameters

You can enable the log-on screen through:

- Right click on desktop
- Personalise
- Click on screen saver
- Tick the *On resume, display the log on screen* box

Otherwise you can edit the registry to do that. [How to.](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55389-log-screen-saver-enable-disable.html)

And finally, since you want to lock the screen when screensaver is on, why don't you just press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> when you leave your desk?

[image]

Comment: With Win+L the screen does not turn black. And I want to activate the screensaver manually. So I need these 3 things at once: 1. Activate manually, 2. make the screens black, 3. login screen on resume.

Comment: @user1580348 then either use the On resume option, or do it through the registry. I used the wrong link, updated my answer. It will now redirect the the correct forum

Comment: The **scrnsave.scr** screensaver (which makes the screen black) does not have a resume option.

Comment: @user1580348 It does on mine. Check the screenshot I uploaded

Comment: @user1580348 You can either change the power options to redirect on the logon screen after a certain amount of time. There is no direct way to enable it. Only by using the options that windows provide

Comment: Logon on resume does not work when the screensaver is activated manually.

Comment: @user1580348 none of these will work until you set a time limit. You can't configure the screensaver from cmd to go to log on screen. You need to set a timeout on power settings or screensaver settings. Or you can write your own script that will lock the computer and go to screensaver

Comment: How could a script work AFTER the screen lock?

Comment: @user1580348 Scripts do not always stop when the screen is locked. Take `ping` for example. Or if you ever used Linux, try `apt-get update` and lock your screen. It will not pause or stop. There are cron jobs that can do that, there are multiple ways to achieve that